# "UIControlEvents has been renamed to UIControl.Event" using Xcode 10 and RxCocoa/CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods

After update to Xcode 10 and install RxCocoa and RxSwift by CocoaPods, there was received a error messages like:

**UIControlState has been renamed to UIControl.State**

**UIControlEvents has been renamed to UIControl.Event**

Answer (score 4):

Appkit and UIKit has API changes in Swift 4.2 (including names), for this reason is necessary update the  local specs repos using `pod update` and installing again the pods.

For more referencia https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1673